# Adding a File Refrence to a .net Core Project results in assembly not found exception

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-standard

After creating a .net core project 1.1  I add a file reference to a .net standard library assembly.

When starting the solution i get a assembly not found exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding Filerefences are currently not supported for .net core 1.X .
Maybe in 2.0 see : https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/10037#issuecomment-285394031 and https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/120

> the .NET Core SDK v1.0 (Visual Studio 2017 RTM) doesn't support direct
>   references to assemblies on disk. Basically the options that will give
>   you success are either  or .
>
> We did enable this scenario for 2.0 though. See dotnet/sdk#120, but
>   those bits have not been released yet. They will be when .NET Core 2.0
>   comes out later this year.

You have the following workaround

**Workaround**

- Package the assembly in a nuget package
- Use Project references if possible